# Как в docker развернуть mysql

Tags: mysql, docker

Есть файл docker-compose:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:33066:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: root
    volumes:
      - ./docker/database:/var/lib/mysql
```

файл `db.sql` находится в `./docker` копирую в контейнер по адресу `/var/lib/mysql`. Как мне сделать так чтобы при `docker-copose build`, файл `db.sql`  автоматический импортировался в базу?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте скрипт, который будет поднимать контейнер и импортировать базу.
У себя не проверял, но должно работать. По крайней мере, смысл должен быть понятен.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker-compose up -d --build
sleep 5 # Подождать 5 сек, чтобы поднялись сервисы в контейнере
docker-compose exec -T mysql sh -c exec mysql -uroot -proot db < docker/db.sql
```